# XSL transform with multiple groups not transforming

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using xsl to transform group records to show up as multiple records and the remaining records show up once and output results to a text file.

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ed:Fin_Data xmlns:ed="urn:com.ad.report/psrpt">
    <ed:Data_Entry>
        <ed:Name>Ione Sys</ed:Name>
        <ed:EAddress>111 Old Blvd. Ste 1&#xa;CITY, ST 12345&#xa;</ed:EAddress>
        <ed:Business_Phone>+1 (111) 9999999</ed:Business_Phone>
        <ed:Pay_Rate>Temporary</ed:Pay_Rate>
        <ed:HAddress>1111 SW Old TER&#xa;CITY, ST 12345&#xa;</ed:HAddress>
        <ed:Name>Idle Bain</ed:Name>
        <ed:ID>X23675</ed:ID>
        <ed:Location>New Blvd.</ed:Location>
        <ed:Start_Date>2018-02-01</ed:Start_Date>
        <ed:End_Date>2018-02-15</ed:End_Date>
        <ed:Pay_Date>2018-02-28</ed:Pay_Date>
        <ed:Prs_Lss>
            <ed:Type>Prs</ed:Type>
            <ed:Amt>3244.09</ed:Amt>
            <ed:YTD>12785.37</ed:YTD>
        </ed:Prs_Lss>
        <ed:Prs_Lss>
            <ed:Type>Lss</ed:Type>
            <ed:Amt>1301.94</ed:Amt>
            <ed:YTD>2864.17</ed:YTD>
        </ed:Prs_Lss>
    </ed:Data_Entry>
</ed:Fin_Data>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="xsl" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ed="urn:com.ad.report/psrpt">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="linefeed" select="'&#xa;'"></xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/ed:Fin_Data">
        <xsl:text>"Name"|"EAddress"|"BusinessPhone"|"PayRate"|"HAddress"|"Name"|"ID"|"Location"|"StartDate"|"EndDate"|"PayDate"|"PrsType"|"PrsAmt"|"PrsYTD"|"LssType"|"LssAmt"|"LssYTD"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ed:Data_Entry/ed:Prs_Lss"/>
    </xsl:template>    

   <xsl:template match="ed:Data_Entry">
        <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ed:Name"/>  
            <xsl:text>"|"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ed:EAddress"/>
            <xsl:text>"|"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ed:EAddress"/>
            <xsl:text>"|"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ed:Business_Phone"/>
            <xsl:text>"|"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ed:Pay_Rate"/>
            <xsl:text>"|"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ed:HAddress"/>
            <xsl:text>"|"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ed:Name"/>
            <xsl:text>"|"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ed:ID"/>
            <xsl:text>"|"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ed:Location"/>
            <xsl:text>"|"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ed:Start_Date"/>
            <xsl:text>"|"</xsl:text>            
            <xsl:value-of select="ed:End_Date"/>
            <xsl:text>"|"</xsl:text>            
            <xsl:value-of select="ed:Pay_Date"/>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>      

   <xsl:template match="ed:Prs_Lss">
        <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ed:Type"/>  
            <xsl:text>"|"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ed:Amt"/>
            <xsl:text>"|"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ed:YTD"/>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result:**

```
"Name"|"EAddress"|"BusinessPhone"|"PayRate"|"HAddress"|"Name"|"ID"|"Location"|"StartDate"|"EndDate"|"PayDate"|"PrsType"|"PrsAmt"|"PrsYTD"|"LssType"|"LssAmt"|"LssYTD"
"Prs"|"3244.09"|"12785.37"
"Lss"|"1301.94"|"2864.17"
```

**Expected Result:**

```
"Name"|"EAddress"|"BusinessPhone"|"PayRate"|"HAddress"|"Name"|"ID"|"Location"|"StartDate"|"EndDate"|"PayDate"|"PrsType"|"PrsAmt"|"PrsYTD"|"LssType"|"LssAmt"|"LssYTD"
"Ione Sys"|"111 Old Blvd. Ste 1 CITY, ST 12345"|"+1 (111) 9999999"|"Temporary"|"1111 SW Old TER CITY, ST 12345"|"Idle Bain"|"X23675"|"New Blvd."|"2018-02-01"|"2018-02-15"|"2018-02-28"|"Prs"|"3244.09"|"12785.37"
""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|"Lss"|"1301.94"|"2864.17"
```

All the elements underneath Data_Entry tag should show up on the very first record and depending on the number of records in the Prs_Lss tag it should show up with all the records. In this example since the Prs_Lss tag has 2 records the first record will have all the data but the second will have blanks till Pay_Date and the remaining data from the Prs_Lss tag.

Comment: Your data contains line breaks - how do you want to handle them?

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k Change the line break to a space instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you try it this way?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ed="urn:com.ad.report/psrpt">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/ed:Fin_Data">
    <!-- HEADER -->             
    <xsl:text>"Name"|"EAddress"|"BusinessPhone"|"PayRate"|"HAddress"|"Name"|"ID"|"Location"|"StartDate"|"EndDate"|"PayDate"|"PrsType"|"PrsAmt"|"PrsYTD"|"LssType"|"LssAmt"|"LssYTD"&#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- ENTRY DATA -->
    <xsl:for-each select="ed:Data_Entry">
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="ed:Name"/>  
        <xsl:text>"|"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(ed:EAddress, '&#xa;', ' ')"/>
        <xsl:text>"|"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="ed:Business_Phone"/>
        <xsl:text>"|"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="ed:Pay_Rate"/>
        <xsl:text>"|"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(ed:HAddress, '&#xa;', ' ')"/>
        <xsl:text>"|"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="ed:Name"/>
        <xsl:text>"|"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="ed:ID"/>
        <xsl:text>"|"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="ed:Location"/>
        <xsl:text>"|"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="ed:Start_Date"/>
        <xsl:text>"|"</xsl:text>            
        <xsl:value-of select="ed:End_Date"/>
        <xsl:text>"|"</xsl:text>            
        <xsl:value-of select="ed:Pay_Date"/>
        <xsl:text>"|"</xsl:text>   
        <!-- FIRST PRS/LSS -->
        <xsl:variable name="first-Prs_Lss" select="ed:Prs_Lss[1]" /> 
        <xsl:value-of select="$first-Prs_Lss/ed:Type"/>  
        <xsl:text>"|"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$first-Prs_Lss/ed:Amt"/>
        <xsl:text>"|"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$first-Prs_Lss/ed:YTD"/>
        <xsl:text>"&#10;</xsl:text>
        <!-- OTHER PRS/LSSs -->
        <xsl:for-each select="ed:Prs_Lss[position() > 1]">
            <xsl:text>""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ed:Type"/>  
            <xsl:text>"|"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ed:Amt"/>
            <xsl:text>"|"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ed:YTD"/>
            <xsl:text>"&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>   

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an **XSLT-2.0** solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="xsl" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ed="urn:com.ad.report/psrpt">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="linefeed" select="'&#xa;'"></xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/ed:Fin_Data">
        <xsl:text>"Name"|"EAddress"|"BusinessPhone"|"PayRate"|"HAddress"|"Name"|"ID"|"Location"|"StartDate"|"EndDate"|"PayDate"|"PrsType"|"PrsAmt"|"PrsYTD"|"LssType"|"LssAmt"|"LssYTD"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ed:Data_Entry/ed:Prs_Lss[1]"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ed:Data_Entry/ed:Prs_Lss[position() > 1]"/>
    </xsl:template>    

   <xsl:template match="ed:Data_Entry">
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ed:Name, replace(ed:EAddress,'&#xa;',' '), ed:Business_Phone, ed:Pay_Rate, replace(ed:HAddress,'&#xa;',' '), ed:Name, ed:ID, ed:Location, ed:Start_Date, ed:End_Date, ed:Pay_Date" separator='"|"' />  
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>      

   <xsl:template match="ed:Prs_Lss[position() = 1]">
        <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../../ed:Data_Entry"/>
        <xsl:text>|"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="ed:Type, ed:Amt, ed:YTD" separator='"|"' />
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>    

   <xsl:template match="ed:Prs_Lss[position() > 1]">
        <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="for $x in ../../ed:Data_Entry/*[not(self::ed:Prs_Lss)] return '&quot;&quot;'" separator="|" />
        <xsl:text>|"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="ed:Type, ed:Amt, ed:YTD" separator='"|"' />
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>   

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Its output is:

```
"Name"|"EAddress"|"BusinessPhone"|"PayRate"|"HAddress"|"Name"|"ID"|"Location"|"StartDate"|"EndDate"|"PayDate"|"PrsType"|"PrsAmt"|"PrsYTD"|"LssType"|"LssAmt"|"LssYTD"
"Ione Sys"|"Idle Bain"|"111 Old Blvd. Ste 1 CITY, ST 12345 "|"+1 (111) 9999999"|"Temporary"|"1111 SW Old TER CITY, ST 12345 "|"Ione Sys"|"Idle Bain"|"X23675"|"New Blvd."|"2018-02-01"|"2018-02-15"|"2018-02-28"|"Prs"|"3244.09"|"12785.37"
""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|"Lss"|"1301.94"|"2864.17"
```

Comment: I didn't go that way, because I didn't want to assume that all the elements will always be there. If one or more are missing, your columns will become misaligned. Without such assumption there will be no real difference between XSLT 1.0 and 2.0.

Comment: Yes. That is one weakness of this approach.

Comment: Hi @zx485 Thank you.